# load jquery files in wordpress using wp_enqueue_script

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to load `jquery` files using `wp_enqueue_script` in `wordpress`. below is the code in my `function.php` file, which is not working, can anyone mention where is the error, thanks

```
function load_myfiles() { // load external file  
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js' );

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // enqueue the external file
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js'); // enqueue the external file  
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_myfiles' );
```

Comment: You should also share the stack trace and all error logs

Comment: hi....I don't get any errors

Comment: hello....the problem is solved...as I am new in wordpress, the function file name should be "functions.php"...but I named it as "function.php"...